# SQL to combine results into one group in the where clause

Tags: sql, where-clause

I have a query

```
SELECT name,
       COUNT (name)
FROM employee
WHERE LOCATION IS LIKE (%%NY%%)
GROUP BY name


name    coount
alex m  10
alex.m  5
alex.ma 1
alex    500
```

How can I combine all the alex's into just one Alex

so that I get the output as

```
name count
alex 516
```

I need something like if it matches `alex%%` then consider it as `alex`

Comment: which dbms you are using?

Comment: `SUM(coount)` instead of `COUNT(name)`. `COUNT` count the number of rows, which will give you 4 in this example.

Comment: This is easy enough for the four cases you have.  But I guess you're also looking for a solution that will group alice, alice m, alice.m and alice.ma (for example).  This is where you need to specify the business logic.  For example you might say name = all chars up to the first space or period.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your dynamic solution on the below for SQL Server.

First, let's see the sample data I worked on:

```
create table #temp
(name varchar(20))

insert into #temp values ('jack')
insert into #temp values ('jack rx')
insert into #temp values ('jack.a')
insert into #temp values ('jack.bb')
insert into #temp values ('jack.xy')
insert into #temp values ('brandon.12')
insert into #temp values ('brandon')
insert into #temp values ('brandon.k7s')
insert into #temp values ('brandon.bg')
insert into #temp values ('Jonathan')
```

Then, we need to employ string operators:

```
;with cte (name, charin, charin_space) as
( 
   select name,CHARINDEX('.',name,0) as charin, CHARINDEX(' ',name,0) as charin_space
   from #temp
)
select name,(case when charin = 0 and charin_space = 0 then name 
                  when charin = 0 and charin_space <> 0 then SUBSTRING(name,0,charin_space) 
                  when charin <> 0 and charin_space = 0 then SUBSTRING(name,0,charin) 
             end) as mainName
into #temp2
from cte
```

The temp table `#temp2` has the names only like `jack`, `brandon` and `jonathan`. All we need is to connect those tables now and use `group by` like:

```
select t2.MainName,COUNT(t2.MainName)
from #temp t1
inner join #temp2 t2 on t1.name = t2.name
group by t2.mainName
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: The data also has space like alex m

Comment: Aah just noticed, we'll need another column like charin_space then and use it in the case statement. I'll update the answer in a few hours when I am back to my pc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get part of the name.  But this only work for SQL Server.  You don't specify which dbms you are using.  The query works with your example, but it will also pick up Alexa, Alexander, ...

```
SELECT LEFT(name, 4),
       SUM(coount)
FROM employee
WHERE LOCATION IS LIKE (%%NY%%)
GROUP BY LEFT(name, 4)
```

Comment: Will count Alexis and Alexander as Alex.

Comment: @jarlh I just give solution based on OP's example.  It will not work either on name longer than 4 characters.

Comment: Hi Eric - totally answers the original question but I think it's likely that they are going to want a solution that deals with more than variants of Alex.  Might be worth adding a line to your answer signposting the limited use case